# Unexpected behaviour of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Most of my little experience with R is concerned with the data. frame's world. However, due I often must struggle with large data.frames I have decided to explore the efficient data.table's world, as a result, I'm paying the consequences of the learning curve. Here is my hypothetical situation:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

> sessioninfo::package_info()
package     * version date       lib source        
data.table  * 1.14.0  2021-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
```

I have a long table, its name is founders, for example

```
> library(data.table)
nfounder <- 1000 
founders <- data.table(ID= seq(1:nfounder), 
                           mum= rep(0, nfounder), 
                           dad= rep(0, nfounder))
```

On the other hand, I have a short table (ped.g), where the variables mum and dad come from the variable ID at founders´ table, that is

```
ped.g <- data.table(ID= seq(1001, 1003), 
                      mum= c(19,23,23), 
                      dad= c(13,13,19))
```

Thus, the pedigree table is building from founders and ped.g tables

```
  pedigree <- rbind(founders, ped.g)
  > pedigree
    ID mum dad
   1:    1   0   0
   2:    2   0   0
   3:    3   0   0
   4:    4   0   0
   5:    5   0   0
   ---             
   999:  999   0   0
  1000: 1000   0   0
  1001: 1001  19  13
  1002: 1002  23  13
  1003: 1003  23  19
```

Thus,

```
  ID <- pedigree[, ID] 
  mum <- match(pedigree[, mum], pedigree[, ID], nomatch=NA)
  dad <- match(pedigree[, dad], pedigree[, ID], nomatch=NA)
```

So that

```
  > mum
  [1] NA NA NA ... NA NA 19 23 23
  > dad
  [1] NA NA NA ... NA NA 13 13 19
```

The following step includes the function generation (“Generation”, in terms of a genetic representation of a family tree that diagrams the inheritance), no matters about this function, the key is the pedigree table

```
  generation <- function(pedigree) {
      ID <- pedigree[, ID] 
      mum <- match(pedigree[, mum], pedigree[, ID], nomatch=NA)
      dad <- match(pedigree[, dad], pedigree[, ID], nomatch=NA)
      n <- dim(pedigree)[1]
      generOld <- gen <- rep(n + 100, n) 
      gen[is.na(mum) & is.na(dad)] <- 0
      i <- 0
      while(!all(generOld == gen)) {
         generOld <- gen
         gen[mum %in% ID[gen==i]] <- i + 1
         gen[dad %in% ID[gen==i]] <- i + 1
         i <- i + 1
         if(i > n + 10) break
      }
     pedigree[, gen := gen]
    return(pedigree)
   }
```

Thus, variable gen is added to the pedigree table, so that gen=0 for founders individuals and gen=1 for first-generation

```
pedigree[, gen := gen]
> pedigree
        ID mum dad gen
   1:    1   0   0   0
   2:    2   0   0   0
   3:    3   0   0   0
   4:    4   0   0   0
   5:    5   0   0   0
   ---                 
   999:  999   0   0   0
  1000: 1000   0   0   0
  1001: 1001  19  13   1
  1002: 1002  23  13   1
  1003: 1003  23  19   1
```

Apparently, everything seems to be fine...! However, this pedigree includes many individuals (ID) that were not selected for "Generation 1" as parents (mum, dad). That is, it must include only parents 13, 19 and 23 (belong to "Generation 1").

Thus, to try to fix the previous issue (retain only selected parents from founders data.table), I utilized the following approach (code)

Recalling that ped.g table is

```
> ped.g
 ID mum dad
 1: 1001  19  13
 2: 1002  23  13
 3: 1003  23  19

ped.tmp <- rbind(founders, ped.g)
parents.G0 <- unique(unlist(ped.g[, c(2, 3)]))
parents.G0 <- as.data.table(parents.G0)
setnames(parents.G0, 'parents.G0', 'parents')
setkey(parents.G0, parents) 
setkey(ped.tmp, ID) 
founders.new <- ped.tmp[parents.G0]

> founders.new
 TreeID mum dad
1:  13   0   0
2:  19   0   0
3:  23   0   0

pedigree.new <- as.data.table(rbind(founders.new, ped.g))
> pedigree.new
ID mum dad
1: 13   0   0
2: 19   0   0
3: 23   0   0
4:  1  19  13
5:  2  23  13
6:  3  23  19
```

Up to here, everything goes smoothly... Now, I will try to build the “Generation” field utilizing the code outlined previously

```
ID <- pedigree.new[, ID]
mum <- match(pedigree.new[, mum], pedigree.new[, ID], nomatch=NA)
dad <- match(pedigree.new[, dad], pedigree.new[, ID], nomatch=NA)
```

First surprise (or difference with respect to the earlier output). Now the variables mum and dad are represented by their index position corresponding to variable ID in the table pedigree.new, instead of its own values (13, 19 and 23), such as in the preceding situation, that is

```
> mum
[1] NA NA NA  2  3  3
> dad
[1] NA NA NA  1  1  2
```

As a consequence, when applying the code to create the variable “Generation” I get a wrong result. That is, for first-generation the variable gen=106 instead of gen=1.

```
pedigree.new[, gen := gen]
> pedigree.new
ID mum dad gen
1: 13   0   0   0
2: 19   0   0   0
3: 23   0   0   0
4:  1  19  13 106
5:  2  23  13 106
6:  3  23  19 106
```

Of course, I have also tried different ways to create the table pedigree (filtered version). For example, see the next attempt.

```
parents.G0 <- unique(unlist(ped.g[, c(2, 3)]))
parents.G0 <- as.data.table(parents.G0)
setnames(parents.G0, 'parents.G0', 'parents')
founders.new2 <- founders[parents.G0, on=.(ID=parents)]
pedigree.new2 <- rbind(founders.new2, ped.g)
```

However, I got the same previous result..

```
 > gen
 [1]   0   0   0 106 106 106
```

In addition, I have compared the attributes and structure of both tables (pedigree vs pedigre.new), however, they look identical. It seems that something is lost at the original pedigree table when it is filtered, and I really want to better understand why data.table objects are behaving in this way. So Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Reformulation of question

1. Input: table pedigree

   ```
   pedigree <- rbind(founders, ped.g)
   > pedigree
         ID   mum dad
   1:    1     0   0
   2:    2     0   0
   3:    3     0   0
   ---   
   13:   13    0   0
   ---   
   19:   19    0   0
   ---   
   23:   23    0   0
   ---              
   999:  999   0   0
   1000: 1000  0   0
   1001: 1001  19  13
   1002: 1002  23  13
   1003: 1003  23  19
   ```

2 ) Processing, this step consists of filter pedigree table so that "keep":

a) ID records which are equal to mum or dad field different of zero on the pedigree table (ID=13, 19, 23), that is

```
       ID mum dad
   1:  13   0   0
   2:  19   0   0
   3:  23   0   0
```

and b) ID records pertaining to those mum and dad different of zero (ID=1001, 1002, 1003), that is

```
          ID   mum dad
   1001: 1001  19  13
   1002: 1002  23  13
   1003: 1003  23  19
```

3 ) Expected output: from the previous step, the filter pedigree table look like

```
  > pedigree.new
    ID  mum dad
  1: 13   0   0
  2: 19   0   0
  3: 23   0   0
  4:  1  19  13
  5:  2  23  13
  6:  3  23  19
```

So that

```
  ID <- pedigree.new[, ID] 
  mum <- match(pedigree.new[, mum], pedigree.new[, ID], nomatch=NA)
  dad <- match(pedigree.new[, dad], pedigree.new[, ID], nomatch=NA)

  > mum
  [1] NA NA NA ... NA NA 19 23 23
  > dad
  [1] NA NA NA ... NA NA 13 13 19
```

As a consequence, when applying the function generation, the new field gen "must look as"

```
  pedigree.new <- generation(pedigree.new)

  > pedigree.new
     ID  mum dad gen
  1: 13   0   0   0
  2: 19   0   0   0
  3: 23   0   0   0
  4:  1  19  13   1
  5:  2  23  13   1
  6:  3  23  19   1
```

4. Example of some attempt (review tables founders and ped.g outlined early)

   ```
   ped.tmp <- rbind(founders, ped.g)
   parents.G0 <- unique(unlist(ped.g[, c(2, 3)]))
   parents.G0 <- as.data.table(parents.G0)
   setnames(parents.G0, 'parents.G0', 'parents')
   setkey(parents.G0, parents) 
   setkey(ped.tmp, ID) 
   founders.new <- ped.tmp[parents.G0]

   > founders.new
      ID mum dad
   1: 13    0   0
   2: 19    0   0
   3: 23    0   0

   pedigree.new2 <- as.data.table(rbind(founders.new, ped.g))

   > pedigree.new2
     ID mum dad
     1: 13   0   0
     2: 19   0   0
     3: 23   0   0
     4:  1  19  13
     5:  2  23  13
     6:  3  23  19

    ID <- pedigree.new2[, ID] 
    mum <- match(pedigree.new2[, mum], pedigree.new2[, ID], nomatch=NA)
    dad <- match(pedigree.new2[, dad], pedigree.new2[, ID], nomatch=NA)

     > mum
    [1] NA NA NA  2  3  3
     > dad
    [1] NA NA NA  1  1  2

    pedigree.new2 <- generation(pedigree.new2)
    > pedigree.new2 
         ID   mum dad gen
    1:   13   0   0   0
    2:   19   0   0   0
    3:   23   0   0   0
    4: 1001  19  13 106
    5: 1002  23  13 106
    6: 1003  23  19 106
   ```

Thus, function generation() fail to define the field gen (ej. ID=1001, 1002 and 1003 has a gen field equal to 106 instead gen=1).

Comment: Could you layout your question with 1.  your input; 2.  your desired output; 3.  (less important but since you already have it) what you've tried.  It's hard to follow what you want to have happen so it's even harder to help.

Comment: Dean, many thanks for your answer, I have reformulated my question defining a function called "generation" so that maintain order. However, the key is the pedigree table resulting after the filter. That is if the pedigree table is ok, the "generation" function works, otherwise, it doesn´t work...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the root cause of the issue is a misunderstanding about the return value of `match()`.

According to `help("match")`, `match()` returns an integer vector giving the *position* in `table` of the first match if there is a match, otherwise `nomatch`.

So, in order to fix the `generation()` function we need to *subset* `ID` with the indices returned by the calls to `match()`:

```
generation <- function(pedigree) {
  ID <- pedigree[, ID]
  # subset ID with indices returned by match()
  mum <- ID[match(pedigree[, mum], pedigree[, ID], nomatch = NA)]
  dad <- ID[match(pedigree[, dad], pedigree[, ID], nomatch = NA)]
  n <- dim(pedigree)[1]
  generOld <- gen <- rep(n + 100, n)
  gen[is.na(mum) & is.na(dad)] <- 0
  i <- 0
  while (!all(generOld == gen)) {
    generOld <- gen
    gen[mum %in% ID[gen == i]] <- i + 1
    gen[dad %in% ID[gen == i]] <- i + 1
    i <- i + 1
    if (i > n + 10)
      break
  }
  pedigree[, gen := gen]
  return(pedigree)
}
```

Now, we get

```
generation(pedigree.new)
pedigree.new
```

> ```
>      ID mum dad gen
> 1:   13   0   0   0
> 2:   19   0   0   0
> 3:   23   0   0   0
> 4: 1001  19  13   1
> 5: 1002  23  13   1
> 6: 1003  23  19   1
> ```

#### Edit: `data.table` replacement for `generation()`

If I understand correctly OP's requirements, the code below is a replacement for OP's `generation()` function which is more idiomatic for `data.table`:

```
generation_dt <- function(pdg) {
  pdg[, gen := 0L]
  for (i in 0:nrow(pdg)) {
    pdg[mum %in% ID[gen == i] | dad %in% ID[gen == i], gen := gen + 1L]
    if (.Last.updated == 0L) break
  }
  pdg[]
}
```

Testing with a use case with 2 generations:

```
pedigree2 <- fread("
  ID  mum  dad
  13    0    0
  19    0    0
  23    0    0
  24    0    0
1001   19   13
1002   23   13
1003   23   19
1004 1003   24
")

generation_dt(pedigree2)
```

> ```
>      ID  mum dad gen
> 1:   13    0   0   0
> 2:   19    0   0   0
> 3:   23    0   0   0
> 4:   24    0   0   0
> 5: 1001   19  13   1
> 6: 1002   23  13   1
> 7: 1003   23  19   1
> 8: 1004 1003  24   2
> ```

`.Last.updated` is a variable which contains the number of rows affected by the most recent `:=` or `set()`.

Comment: Uwe, many thanks for your answer, the issue was fixed...! However, I'm still not clear about data.table object's behaviour, and maybe either about match() function. I mean, according to my understanding, 
the match function returns the index position. However, if you consider the original pedigree table (dim(pedigree)=1003x3) and then use the match function but without including ID as you suggested, 
it returns the value of mum/dad instead of its position in the pedigree. ie ID <- pedigree[, ID]
 mum <- match(pedigree[, mum], pedigree[, ID], nomatch=NA)
 > mum
[1]  NA ... NA 19 23 23

Comment: In case of the original pedigree table with 1003 rows, it is just by coincidence that `match(...)`returns the same value as `ID[match(...)` because `ID` is identical with the row number / position.

Comment: Good job, Uwe... !!! Your answer overcomes my expectations. I mean, apart from clarifying the doubt about the possible inconsistency of the match() function, you improve the function generation., i.e., generation_dt.

Many thank again....!

Comment: Dear @Rob, I just noted that this question is still in the state of "unanswered" because the answer is not marked as "accepted". Would you mind to accept the answer following the guideline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please?